# Replace the "@" for reference a row of a table with another "kind" of reference to that row

Tags: excel, excel-tables, structured-references

[image: Screenshot]

I want, if possible, to replace the "@" in the formula: =SUM(COUNTIFS(MyTable[@[a1]:[a6]],"B",Cond2,"S"), COUNTIFS(MyTable[@[a1]:[a6]],"A",Cond1,"<>0")) which it counts the cells of "MyTable" that fulfill some conditions that are found above "MyTable" at the same column in named regions "Cond1" and "Cond2".

The reason is to be able to move the "Result" column of "MyTable" to another place, but also, to keep the dynamic nature of "Result", so if I add another row to "MyTable" (Case4), to update the results.
Currently, I hide the "Result" column by hiding the H column of the spreadsheet, but I think may be a better solution to this.